# codeigniter start timer on button click and display

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, if-statement, timer

Quick FYI: I am learning. I have some experience in PHP and very little to none in java. Ive been downed on posts before because of this. So trying one more time.

I am trying to start a timer for 24 hours on a button click, and display this timer. After this 24 hours, it updates tables in database. This button is inside an if statement which seems to make it harder.

So when this button is clicked, it starts the 24 hour timer, HH:MM:SS. I have tried a few timer scripts, but im unsure how to use them. Again, no real experience in java. This was the timer script i found.

```
 <script> 
function Timer(duration, display) 
{
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt((timer /3600)%24, 10)
        minutes = parseInt((timer / 60)%60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(hours +":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);

                --timer;
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function start($) 
{
    var twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60;
    var display = $('#remainingTime');
    Timer(twentyFourHours, display);
});


 
 </script>
```

And this is the statement:

```
 <? if($provinces['nation_name'] == "") {
     '<center><button onclick="start()">Start Nation</button></center>';
          } 
?>
```

I think my problem is getting it to read the function in the IF statement. I haven't gotten to updating after timer, just trying to get this to work first.

Comment: the button is present, trying to get it to start timer onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to simulate what you had asked in the question. I did a few changes in the original code to explain how the task can be achieved. Make sure to do the suitable changes once you're satisfied with the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span id="remainingTime">Timer</span>

        <?PHP
            // Replace below if condition with your if condition.
            if(true) {
                echo("<button onclick='start()'>Start Nation</button>");
            }
        ?>

        <script>
            function Timer(duration, display) {
                let timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;

                let setIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
                    hours = parseInt((timer / 3600) % 24, 10)
                    minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10)
                    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                    display.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

                    --timer;
                    if (timer === -1) {
                        clearInterval(setIntervalId);
                        // Perform the necessary operation here like triggering event to update the database.
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

            function start() {
                // For testing purpose set the value to 10 seconds.
                let twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60;
                const display = $('#remainingTime');
                Timer(twentyFourHours, display);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've made this an independent file so that you could run it independently without requiring anything else and you don't get confused with the involvement of other code snippets.

You can copy and paste the above code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler) to test and see its working.

Two significant changes that I've done:

1. Put the button inside the `echo` function inside PHP tags.
2. Used `clearInterval`. If you don't use `clearInterval`, then the timer would go on decreasing and you'll start to get negative values. You can learn more about `clearInterval` from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). I suggest you remove `clearInterval` once and see the results.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Perfect, its displaying the timer now. only question, how do i get it so they can only press it once, and doesn't refresh when i reload? or do i need to connect the timer to the database for that?

Comment: For that, you can save the value in a database but since it's being updated every second, it won't be a very practical approach. For these kinds of cases, you can use localStorage API available on the window object. Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Apart from saving the current timer value in localStorage, you also check if timer has already started, then perform no action when user clicks the start button.

Comment: thank you, i looking into localstorage as it seem to be a better approach.